# Angular Directive + $observe

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I seem to have mis-understood how $observe works. From the following example ([plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/lhVHoON9y4K5Jf5643p9?p=preview)).

HTML

```
<html ng-app="record">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0-rc2" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="IndexController">
  <input type="text" value="{{src}}"/>
  <input type="text" value="{{RecordAddress}}"/>
  <input type="text" value="{{FlashVars}}"/>
  <input type="button" ng-click="handleClick()" value="click me"/>
    <record src="{{src}}"></record>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS

```
angular.module('record',[])
.controller("IndexController", function($scope)
{
  console.log('controller called')
  $scope.handleClick = function()
  {
    console.log('handleClick - called');
    $scope.RecordAddress = 'rtmp://thisIsAnAddress';
    $scope.FlashVars = 'userid=SomeId&filename=http://localhost/Content/ThisIsAnAddress/player.swf&mediaFormat=_video.mp4&mediaServerAddress=rtmp://ThisIsAnAddress&culture=en-GB'
    $scope.src = $scope.RecordAddress+ '`' + $scope.FlashVars;
  }
})
.directive('record', function ($location) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    current: '=current'
                },
                link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
                    console.log('record directive - called');
                    console.log(attr);

                    attr.$observe('src', function(value)
                        {
                            console.log('record observe callback called!');
                            console.log('The value is: '+ value);
                            if(value && value !='recordValues')
                            {
                                var values = value.split('`');
                                console.log('video values:')
                                console.log(values);
                                element.html('<object position="relative" width="519px" height="520px" data="'+values[0]+'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="FlashVars" value="'+values[1]+'" /><param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always" /></object>');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                element.html("<div>Please wait</div>")
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        });
```

I'd expect the "object" to be rendered when the button is clicked as opposed to the "please wait" that should appear when the settings are not ready. However it is not called when the "src" attribute is seemingly updated. Could somebody explain to me why this example doesn't work?

Comment: I think you should look at this too: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a few things going on at once, which always makes for fun debugging.  I suspect $watch might work better for you. But also, using the `element.html()` calls was overwriting the variable within the html that you were trying to watch.

I've made a few changes (all contained within your directive) and have some working code below (where I added a template to place your message in- of course there's a variety of other ways to do the same thing).

```
directive('record', function ($location,$sce) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div ng-bind-html="trustedMsg"></div>',
            link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
                console.log('record directive - called');
                console.log(attr);

                $scope.$watch('src', function(value)
                    {
                        console.log('record observe callback called!');
                        console.log('The value is: '+ value);
                        if(value && value !='recordValues')
                        {
                            var values = value.split('`');
                            console.log('video values:')
                            console.log(values);
                            $scope.message='<object position="relative" width="519px" height="520px" data="'+values[0]+'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="FlashVars" value="'+values[1]+'" /><param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always" /></object>';
                            $scope.trustedMsg = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.message);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $scope.message="<div>Please wait</div>";
                            $scope.trustedMsg = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.message);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    });
```

Also, if you prefer to stick with your attr.$observe call then you could change your html from:

```
<record src='{{src}}'></record>
```

to:

```
<record src='src'></record>
```

Edit: I updated (and tested) the code so message now supports html, as your code does.  (http://plnkr.co/edit/K18Djio1NfSaHIWOXpeJ)

Comment: I'm loving this code but $sce is 1.2 only? What did we do prior to this?

Comment: @Quibblesome, You're right that $sce was included by default starting with 1.2.  But there's an easy solution pre-1.2.   Prior to 1.2 you could use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` (which was removed in 1.2).  So, for pre-1.2 just remove the references to $sce and use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` instead of `ng-bind-html` (and, obviously, pass in `message` instead of `trustedMsg` (which you removed when you removed $sce references))

Answer (score 5):

For directives with isolated scope the element you're applying directive to doesn't inherit scope of the parent. So you won't see any `{{src}}` variable there - it will be always empty.

There are two ways you can communicate with external world using attributes for directive with **isolated scope**:

- Use `src="{{$parent.src}}"` but it's a little hackish
- Use @ attribute mapping for one-way binding

```
scope: {
    src: '@src'
}
```

And then following code will work:

```
$attrs.$observe('src', function(value) {
  //some action
});
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't choose this answer but KayakDave created a complete sample. What I love about you though is teaching me a little more about isolated scopes. The "copying over" of the src in the scope declaration is very cool and I didn't know it worked that way so I wanted to express my thanks individually for it. :)

Comment: Sure, but really I think that in your case you should use $observe, because for `src` there is only one way binding there. You don't change it back from the directive to the "external world". And also $observe is a little faster than $watch.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misusing the $observe function, though I may just not understand 100% of what you're trying to do.  I think a better way to do what you want would to be set the proper `src` value on your `$scope` within your controller, and then use `$watch` to detect changes to that value.  The following is how I would suggest you do that:

In your controller:

```
$scope.handleClick = function(){
    console.log('handleClick - called');
    $scope.RecordAddress = 'rtmp://thisIsAnAddress';
    $scope.FlashVars = 'userid=SomeId&filena...';

    //Now set the src on the scope as you already had:
    $scope.source = $scope.RecordAddress+ '`' + $scope.FlashVars;
}
```

In your html view:

```
<!-- remove the binding braces so you're just passing a regular attribute -->
<record src="source"></record>
```

In your directive:

```
//add a simple update function (for cleanliness)
function update(value){
    if(value && value !='recordValues'){
        var values = value.split('`');
        element.html('INSERT YOUR LONG HTML STRING HERE');
    }else{
        element.html("<div>Please wait</div>")
    }
}

// get any initial value for the 'source' variable
var value = scope.$eval(attrs.src);   // this will return the scope's source variable
if(value) update(value);

// watch for any changes to that variable on the scope
scope.$watch(attrs.src, update);
```

NOTE:  Even though I believe the above code will work for what you want, I think its not really the best way to do it.  You are really passing two values to your directive from your controller: 1) `RecordAddress` and 2) `FlashVars`.  I would suggest that you add two separate attributes to your `record` element:

```
<record address="addr" flash-vars="flashVars"></record>
```

And then you would bind to them separately from your directive as:

```
function update(addr, flashVars){ ... }

scope.$eval(addrs.address, function(value){ ... });
scope.$eval(addrs.flashVars, function(value){ ... });

scope.$watch(addrs.address, ...);
scope.$watch(addrs.flashVars, ...);
```

This would save you from having to split the values in the directive.

Comment: thanks for the comment! DaveKayak won through his complete example but I really wanted to express gratitude for helping me out here. THANKEE!!!! :)